# I'm trying to dockerize my nestjs project with mongodb but there is a problem with package.json

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs, nest

This is my Dockerfile inside nestjs project,located at the root of the nestjs folder

```
FROM node:21 AS production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/api

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --global @nestjs/cli
RUN npm install --only=production
RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install netcat-openbsd
RUN npm install
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm run start:prod"]
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml file at the root of the project:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongodb:
    image : mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./database:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - shared-network
    restart: always

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx-prod
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command: /bin/sh -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    depends_on:
      - api-prod
      - app-prod
    networks:
      - shared-network

  api-prod:
    container_name: nestjs_api_prod
    image: nestjs-api-prod:1.0.0
    build:
      context: nestjs-cars-app
      target: production
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/api
      - /usr/src/api/node_modules
    command: npm run start:prod
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - shared-network
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "http://api-prod:9000"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 6

  app-prod:
    container_name: react_app_prod
    image: react-app-prod:1.0.0
    build:
      context: my-app
      target: production
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm run start:prod
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - shared-network
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  shared-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I have tried to docker-compose build and it's ok. But when I try docker-compose up, I keep getting this error:

nestjs_api_prod  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
nestjs_api_prod  | npm ERR! syscall open
nestjs_api_prod  | npm ERR! path /usr/src/api/package.json
nestjs_api_prod  | npm ERR! errno -2
nestjs_api_prod  | npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/api/package.json'
nestjs_api_prod  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
nestjs_api_prod  | npm ERR! enoent
nestjs_api_prod  |
nestjs_api_prod  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-01-11T01_00_18_051Z-debug-0.log
nestjs_api_prod exited with code 254

For more info this is my project directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyHZj.jpg)